# How to position a CardView inside another CardView , like nested CardViews?

Tags: android, cardview

I want to make a layout like the one below and so this needs a CardView inside another CardView and I am not able to position it accordingly. I don't know why  but I can't position the cards inside another one properly. I have already tried to position it like the normal layouts, but that didn't work. Here is the expected design:

[image]

Comment: Please try to show us what you've achieved so far?

Answer (score 0):

use any other layout like linear layout or relative layout inside the cardview to position it accordingly,otherwise there will be problems as cardview is related to frame layout and it doesn't support this kinda positioning constrains